# how to change text color continously

Tags: python, console

I have a program that changes the color of an ASCII art in a while loop.
but when I run, it creates another text. I wanted to just create the color without creating a new text

here is my code:

```py
from rich import print
import random
import time
import sys

animation_time = 10

def generate_random_color():
    random_color = ["red", "blue", "magenta", "yellow", "purple"]
    return random.choice(random_color)

while True:
    color = generate_random_color()
    text = f"[{color}] \
\n██████╗ ██╗ ██████╗ ███████╗ \
\n██╔══██╗██║██╔═══██╗██╔════╝ \
\n██████╔╝██║██║   ██║███████╗ \
\n██╔══██╗██║██║   ██║╚════██║ \
\n██████╔╝██║╚██████╔╝███████║ \
\n╚═════╝ ╚═╝ ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝ \
[/]"
    
    print(text, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: some terminals/consoles has special text codes to clear screen. And then you can `print` this code and then print you text in the same place but with differen color. For example in Bash terminal you can clear screen with `print("\033c")`

Comment: Can you patch your string together using e.g. string formatting or simple addition? Something like `output_string = f"[{color}] + input_string`?

Comment: What you will want to look at is python's [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) you need to move the cursor back to repaint the screen.

Comment: you should check in `rich` documentation if it doesn't have special codes to move cursor or to clear terminal.

Comment: in Linux terminal you can use `print("\033[%d;%dH" % (y, x))` to move cursor to position `x,y`. And then you can write your text again in the same place

Answer (score 0):

I got it already. I just need to clear the screen every time instead of carriage return